# Liquibase executes changeset several times in single Maven build

Tags: maven, teamcity, liquibase

I am observing some strange Liquibase behavior when I run simple Maven project on TeamCity build agent.

Maven project structure:

```
changelogs/
databaseChangeLog.xml
pom.xml
```

Run command: mvn liquibase:update

databaseChangeLogs.xml contains next line: `<includeAll path="changelogs/"/>`

But build log contains duplication records:

```
liquibase: databaseChangeLog.xml: /home/teamcity/BuildAgent/work/28fe713da351c06d/changelogs/1.xml: ChangeSet /home/teamcity/BuildAgent/work/28fe713da351c06d/changelogs/1.xml ran successfully in 40ms

liquibase: databaseChangeLog.xml:  Custom SQL executed
liquibase: databaseChangeLog.xml: changelogs/1.xml: ChangeSet changelogs/1.xml ran successfully in 36ms
```

So seems like Liquibase picked up changeset twice from different locations: from build agent's build folder and root of the project.

Does anybody meet the same issue?
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Liquibase has kinda a design flaw which lays in considering at our first glance "identical" change sets as different. To bypass such a peculiarity you can use `logicalFilePath` attribute either on `databaseChangeLog` tag or on every `changeSet` tag. This one will add another level of identity, uniqueness to a your change set.